# Design issue - sort array in controller or view?

Tags: java, jsp, model-view-controller

I am developing an MVC based application. I have an array that contains names of clients. The array is populated from a database.

The **controller** (Java) passes this array to the **view** (JSP) and the view renders it. The list of clients needs to be displayed in an ascending order. Also, if there is client called XYZ, then that XYZ client should always be displayed first in the list. There are other such rules.

The question is, **from a *design* perspective, where should the sorting happen?** Should it happen in the controller (Java) or in the view (JSP)?

As an aside note, I also need to mention that I am more comfortable programming in Java than in JSP/JavaScript. If there is no "right" or "wrong" way of doing it, then I would definitely prefer sorting it in the controller itself.

Also, from a performance perspective, which is better?

Comment: The sorting should happen in the controller. The view should be given the data ready for use.

Comment: why not sort in database itself ?

Comment: @sanbhat , I don't have control over the database queries. Also, special rules for sorting also apply.

Comment: in the database you should do natural ordering, and for special cases, in controller/presenter ,

Comment: It can be in presenter or controller, depending your design. If when sorting you need to make sure to retrieve the data **one more time**, do it in controller, if just for presentation purposes, do it in the view (probably with JavaScript).

Comment: @sanbhat that depends if the column to sort has an index in your database table.

Comment: I'd say it depends on why it's being sorted. If it's somehow an intrinsic property of the data, so for example if the elements were prioritized and other code should "see" some elements before others, or if all views you'd want of the data should be sorted the same way, then that argues for it being sorted in the model.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the view can contain logic that is specific for view only like sorting some data, it all depends on what OP tries to achieve.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I would agree that view can have logic but IMO it's more for formatting. Is sorting also formatting? Maybe. If there's a logical reason the data should be sorted, I would do in the controller (or model if possible).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis if is static data that won't change but for presentation purposes, then it should go in view.

Comment: Sorry, you don't sort the data in Controller but in Model (at least that you really sort the data in the Servlet instead of a business logic class like EJB).

Answer (score 3):

From the design perspective, the controller should control the rules of the sorting, but it should not be performing the sorting itself. Rather, it should delegate this task to the model. In the ideal world, controller should not make any modifications to the data, only tell the model how it wants the data to be modified.

Unfortunately, reality often interferes with ideal designs: when users are allowed to control sorting, for example by clicking column headers, a shortcut that allows the view to sort the data is often taken to reduce the number of roundtrips to the model (which is often implemented as a database) thus offloading the RDBMS. An unfortunate side effect of this decision is lack of consistency with paging: sorting in a view orders the data on the current page, ignoring the data in other pages that should come before or after what's currently displayed. This shortcoming is often presented to users as a "feature".

In your case, the ordering appears part of "business rules": the fact that the "XYZ" record must remain on the top, and that there are "other such rules" suggests that sorting is *not* a purely visual concern. Consider designing a "sort descriptor" of some kind that can hold "metadata" about the sort. Your controller should create an instance of this "sort descriptor", and pass it to the model for processing. The model should "interpret" the content of the descriptor, and produce the data in the correct order.

Comment: I always thought that model simply refers to the data and that all operations on the data would be performed by the Controller or the View. But you're saying that the model should do the sorting, so you mean the database does the sort?

Comment: @CodeBlue Model includes the data as well as the classes that operate on that data and interact with the persistence layer to fetch or to store.

Comment: @CodeBlue Model is not only the data, but also the business rules surrounding it. If the model can "convince" the database to perform the sort for it, for example, by converting the sort descriptor that came from the controller into SQL's `ORDER BY`, then the database will do the sorting for your model. If the model cannot do it in the database for one reason or the other, it could do sorting by itself.

Answer (score 0):

The sorting can be done in the SQL Query itself (if the sorting is not complicated) and then you can just pass the data to the view through the controller.

However, if you have a big set of rules that cannot be all achieved in the SQL statement, I would simply just do it in the controller.

You can always create a stored procedure and just call that, it really is a preference in my opinion.

Just for sake of MVC pattern I like to put it in the controller, since the controller is meant for this kind of thing.

Comment: *Just for sake of MVC pattern I like to put it in the controller, since the controller is meant for this kind of thing* If you display static data (that comes from your database) that never changes until you have to restart the server (or another big event like that) then do the sort in the View. No need to do a new request/response process when this can be easily done in the view

Comment: that is true, my assumption was he is using an database where data changes.  i.e. new client is added by another user.  However I should of mentioned that.  Thank you

Comment: There are too many considerations to take into account to provide an answer to this question. By the way, if sorting happens on database, then you're sorting on Model instead of Controller.

Answer (score 0):

From a design perspective, I'd say the controller should have no knowledge of HOW the view displays the data; the fact it's sorted and has other rules is purely a display constraint; heck, the date doesn't even need to be ordered in the controller at all, it might be in a `HashMap` or such.

That being said, it might be more efficient ordering things in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

The *default* sort order should be handled at the database. It's highly optimized to do such stuff provided the database design also takes care of putting the right indexes in place (like a clustered index on the column the default sort is being done on). But, even in the worst case scenario it would sort no later than the time it would take to do in the code.

The *secondary* sort orders should be handled in the *view* layer because that's it's job - handle how the data is displayed. The *view* can ideally employ `Comparator`s to support different sort orders. If you have a *view* of tabular data and a user requests for a sort on some other column; it should be sorted by the *view* (not the *controller* or *model*).

The *controller* has nothing to do with it. It simply orchestrates the flow or moves data out of the *model*; identifies the right *view* and makes it available for consumption by the *view*. *Controller* does not process data; it's the *model*'s job.

But, sorting is not about processing; it's about rendering in some order which should remain flexible and depend on the *view*. By doing it in the *model*, you're imposing it's will on how data should be displayed and depending on what kind of application it is (web or desktop) maybe sorting things twice.

The only use case that I can see for sorting in the *model* is to provide a *default* sort order when your data source isn't sorting at all (say, it's not a database, it's a web service) or, when you want to override the order shared by a set of *views* (that are not sorting the data themselves).